# What do people want to express when they ask "What is it with something?"

Tags: meaning-in-context

Plot:
An American housewife moved to Westport and people only drank juice rather than alcohol in there. She said,

> What is it with Westport and the juice?

I don't think this is ask the connection between Westport and juice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that she thinks that there's a reason that the people like the juice this much, and she wants to know the history about the reason.
In simple words,

> "What's with ___?" is a casual way to **ask why** something is happening.